# CURL php returns wrong STARTTRANSFER time

Tags: php, curl, xampp

SYSTEM: Win10 Prof,
XAMPP Version: 7.1.10

I am currently sending a request via curl to a rest API. After curl_exec() I want to check the time the curl request was running.

When checking the time returns with curl_getinfo most of the time the values are correct, but sometimes STARTTRANSFER returns an far away time from real time response.

**Example normal:**

```
|<br>
 |--NAMELOOKUP 0.015 (Time from start until name resolving completed)<br>
 |--|--CONNECT 0.015 (Time from start until remote host or proxy completed) 
 <br>
 |--|--|--APPCONNECT 0.046 (Time from start until SSL/SSH handshake completed)<br>
  |--|--|--|--PRETRANSFER 0.046 (Time from start until just before the transfer begins)<br>
   |--|--|--|--|--STARTTRANSFER 1.203 (Time from start until just when the first byte is received)<br>
   |--|--|--|--|--|--TOTAL 1.203 (Total time of previous transfer)<br>
   |--|--|--|--|--|--REDIRECT 0 (Time taken for all redirect steps before the final transfer)<br>

   |<br>
   |--NAMELOOKUP 0.031 (Time from start until name resolving completed)<br>
   |--|--CONNECT 0.031 (Time from start until remote host or proxy completed)<br>
   |--|--|--APPCONNECT 0.078 (Time from start until SSL/SSH handshake completed) 
        <br>
    |--|--|--|--PRETRANSFER 0.078 (Time from start until just before the transfer begins)<br>
     |--|--|--|--|--STARTTRANSFER 0.75 (Time from start until just when the first byte is received)<br>
     |--|--|--|--|--|--TOTAL 0.75 (Total time of previous transfer)<br>
    |--|--|--|--|--|--REDIRECT 0 (Time taken for all redirect steps before the final transfer)<br>
```

**And than sometimes this response:**

```
    |--NAMELOOKUP 0.031 (Time from start until name resolving completed)<br>
    |--|--CONNECT 0.031 (Time from start until remote host or proxy completed)<br>
   |--|--|--APPCONNECT 0.078 (Time from start until SSL/SSH handshake completed)<br>
   |--|--|--|--PRETRANSFER 0.078 (Time from start until just before the transfer begins)<br>
   |--|--|--|--|--STARTTRANSFER 4298.732296 (Time from start until just when the first byte is received)<br>
   |--|--|--|--|--|--TOTAL 4298.732296 (Total time of previous transfer)<br>
   |--|--|--|--|--|--REDIRECT 0 (Time taken for all redirect steps before the final transfer)<br>
```

At all times the processing time is within 1-2 seconds from load page to get the response printed.

This issue only happens when starting the script within xampp on the windows machine. When running it on a linux (debian) system it doesn't happen.

Any idea what's going wrong on windows with curl and xampp at this time?